# Python string list to string

Tags: python

I am doing something painfuly simple, and rather than looping over the list, and += everything, I was wondering if there was a "sleezier" way to do it.

Simple concept I have something like:

```
some_string_array = [  "s", "t", "a", "c", "k", " ", "o", "v", "e", "r", "f", "l", "o","w" ]
some_string = some_string_array.--sleezy built-in flatten--() 
print(some_string)
```

And the result would be simply `stack overflow`

I am sure it is painfuly simple, but I couldn't find a good way to search for this online.

Thanks.

Comment: IMO, the solution @Sven Marnach provided is elegant, rather than sleazy.

Comment: Agreed, I knew it was simple ;)  I gotta wait my 4 mins, then i will accept.  I also revised the question for you S. Lott

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use

```
"".join(some_string_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

even more sleazier:

```
reduce(lambda a,b:a+b,some_string_array)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce